# Artifactory - type mismatch error with afterDownloadError()

Tags: plugins, artifactory

I'm writing a plugin leveraging the afterDownloadError hook described here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Download

However, I get the following error with this code when I attempt to download a file.
My code:

```
import org.artifactory.request.Request

download {
  afterDownloadError  { Request request ->
   log.info(request.getRepoPath().getPath())
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Could not process download request: Script execution error: failed to call plugin execution point 'afterDownloadError' - expected a method with arguments types (org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.HttpArtifactoryRequest)"
```

I'm using Artifactory Pro 5.1.4.  I also tried importing and passing HttpArtifactoryRequest to the afterDownloadError closure but that didn't work either.  It appears that there is either a bug or documentation issue here, or both.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll answer my own post - my script was throwing an exception in the afterDownloadError closure but the error message was a bit confusing until I realized what was happening.